# Dynamically loading kendo ScrollView in Angular ng-template not working

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, ng-template

I am trying to make this sample dynamic by pulling items[] from database:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbonf1?file=app/app.component.ts

Therefore, I call a service to load items:

```
 public isFormReady: boolean = false;
 public items: any[] = [];
//loading items
 ngOnInit() {
this.isFormReady = false;
this._gwfoService.GetScrollViewItems().subscribe(
  (result: ScrollViewItems[]) => {
    this.items = result;
    console.log('items', this.items);
  }
);
this.isFormReady = true;
//after loading all controls
setInterval(() => {
  this.scrollview.next();
}, 5000)
```

}

console.log gives me:
items

```
Array(3)
0: {title: "2019 Anti-Money Laundering training due by 10/21/2019", url: "https://..path../Content/img/SV02.png"}
1: {title: "Hierarchy going live on....", url: "https://..path../Content/img/SV03.jpg"}
2: {title: "GWFO Town Hall on 7/25/2019", url: "https://..path../Content/img/SV01.jpg"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

and the error I get is:

```
MyComponent.html:17 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (MyComponent.html:17)
```

Basically 'item' is undefined and can't read 'title' or 'url' in HTML. Please guide what shall I do to define let-item="item" or fix my code. I can't figure out if let-item="item" is another notation for *ngFor="let item of items". I tried replacing but did not work. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="isFormReady==true">
  isFormReady {{isFormReady}}
  <div style="background-image:url('https://...my path/Resources/images/Header.png');
          background-size:cover; color:#ffffff; height: 300px; text-shadow:0.25px 0.25px #000000;">

       <kendo-scrollview #scrollview
                          [data]="items"
                          [width]="width"
                          [height]="height"
                          [animate]="animate"
                          [arrows]="true"
                          [endless]="true"
                          [pageable]="true">

          <ng-template let-item="item">
            <h2 class="demo-title">{{item.title}}</h2>
            <img src='{{item.url}}' alt='{{item.title}}'
                 [ngStyle]="{minWidth: width}"
                 draggable="false" />
          </ng-template>
        </kendo-scrollview>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't render `kendo-scrollview` until `items` has been populated.

Comment: Noremac, with your suggestion I have updated my code, so the title and url are now loading. However, now I am getting error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined. It is throwing on line  this.scrollview.next();

Comment: Move `setInterval(() => { this.scrollview.next(); }, 5000)` within the subscribe after `this.items` is set. The `*ngIf` added to the kendo scrollview to fix the last problem removes the element of the DOM. Since `#scrollview` is nowhere to be found in the DOM, `this.scrollview` is undefined at the time ngOnInit() runs, but `this.scrollview` will be defined one change detection cycle after you set `this.items`.

Comment: Normac, Thank you so much! I would have never realized that *ngIf is removing #scrollview from the DOM